# Fluent NHibernate saving join record

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, fluent

I've got 3 tables in SQL... which look like the following

Now this maps to the following domain objects

```
    public abstract class Case
    {
        public virtual DateTime Imported { get; set; }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Meeting
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual string LineManager { get; set; }
        public virtual Case Case { get; set; }

    }
    public class SCase : Case
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string reason { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Meeting> Meeting { get; set; } 

    }

This works fine when I query it using the following fluent configuration

   public class PMap : ClassMap<Case>
    {
        public PMap()
        {

            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        }
    }

    public class ParentMap : ClassMap<SCase>
    {
        public ParentMap()
        {

            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.reason);
            //Map(x => x.Imported);
            Join("[Case]", m =>
                {
                    m.Fetch.Join();
                    m.KeyColumn("Id");
            });


        }
    }
```

But I don't understand why it won't save! Surely if it can read and know how to map the thing then it must be able to save it??

I get the following error:

> {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CaseId', table
>   'Scratchpad.dbo.SCase; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Why is it trying to insert `CaseID`? Surely since its a join it should insert the Id from `SCase`??